# How to Count the occurances of all entities in a python spacy document?

Tags: python, count, nlp, aggregate, spacy

I am using SciSpasy to identify all entities in a text document. From this, I would like to return a two column data frame. With the left column being a list of unique entities found in the text document and the right side being the number of times the entity appears in the document. How can I go about this using spacy?

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37253326/how-to-find-the-most-common-words-using-spacy

Comment: Also: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/139

Comment: Not really. It's not counting the individual entities, just the complete set.

Comment: Give us a sample of data and what is your expectation?

Answer (score 1):

You can just count things yourself.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load(...) # load your model

from collections import Counter

ents = Counter()

text = ... # your text
for ent in nlp(text).ents:
    ents[f"{ent.label_}:{ent.text}"] += 1

for key, val in ents.items():
    print(val, key, sep="\t")
```

Comment: It looks a bit counterintuitive to create an empty `Counter()` then fill it manually, rather than initialising it directly with the iterable.